# Scrollbars and align to client in a nested form

Tags: delphi

My app has a form - which is used to design other forms and contains an Object Inspector (bas ascii art follows)

```
-----------------------
|obj | design forms   | 
|insp| here           |
|    |                |
-----------------------
```

so, the app''s main form contains the object form and another form onto which components can be placed (there's also a toolbar at the top to select components, but I haven't shown that).

Now, If I make the main form larger, I would like the contents to expand to fit it ...

```
-------------------------------
|obj | design forms           | 
|insp| here                   |
|    |                        |
|    |                        |
|    |                        |
-------------------------------
```

so my "form designer" form has `Align := alClient;`

but, if I place a component on it, so that it overlaps the edge ...

```
-------------------------------
|obj | design forms           | 
|insp| here              -----------
|    |                   |component|
|    |                   -----------
|    |                        |
-------------------------------
```

the screen of course shows

```
-------------------------------
|obj | design forms           |
|insp| here              -----|
|    |                   |comp|
|    |                   -----|
|    |                        |
-------------------------------
```

and I would like an auto scroll bar.

But, it seems that `Align := alClient;` overrides AutoScroll := true;

Any idea how to resolve this conflict?
1) the designer area should shrink and grow, always filling the right part of the main form as the main form is resized
2) if a component is placed which would overhang the edge of the designer form then it should grow scroll bar(s)

**OR** am I totally missing the point? I have code that handles the placing of the component - should I be checking there if I need to add scrollbars?

Comment: What type is the container component that's holding the contents of the form being designed? I think the standard `TScrollBox` behaves the way you want.

Comment: +1 for the +1 for the ascii art ;-)

Comment: +1 for "what type?". It ultimately derives from TScrollingWinControl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a relatively easy solution would be to switch the form's `Align` to `alNone` and position and size it on the parent form's resize event. Presumably you've got a splitter in there whose size events you would also have to listen to.

So long as you only have the inspector and the design form then that's a pretty simple solution to implement.  If you have more tool windows in there then it would get more tricky but the basic idea can be extended.

Comment: +1 Yup, there is a splitter and that sounds like a neat solution. I will coed it & get back to you. Thanks

Comment: @Mawg: I once left a praising comment implying that I had also upvoted the answer I was commenting on. It later turned out that I actually failed to upvote. Seems like the same happened to you this time. That, or your comment was intended for a completely different answer which just happened to be about some splitter too (a time splitter, maybe), and it landed here by some mistake. :)

Comment: +1 for your answer and +1 for your comment. Sorry about that.  It will take a while to code this, so I won't award the answer just yet, in case someone, somehow posts a better answer - but I am not holding my breath. Thanks for leading me in the right direction

Comment: The problem is that I want the nested form to be capable of being bigger than the main form, or even the monitor, by adding scroll bars to it, so I can't just resize it. I do need scroll bars.

Comment: Well no that's not the case. When you resize it so that the controls are outside the panel boundaries, that's when the scroll bars appear.

Comment: or don't, as the case may be ;-)

Comment: @Mawg It seems to work fine for me. But I'm looking for the scrollbars on the design form rather than the overall container. Where do you want the scrollbars to be?

Comment: I want them on the container, but it is not working in my app, even though I coded a very simple version where it did work. I suspect that in my main app have conflicts between autoscroll and alignment or some such, but, short of posting the entire code (18k lines in 100+ files) I don't see how I'll find it. Unless some suggests "such and such will override the autoscroll" ... sigh

Comment: Thank for all of your help, David