# Why can't I see my scroll bars?

Tags: delphi

I have positioned a nested form on the applications main form along with another control and a TSplitter, as stated in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800915/scrollbars-and-align-to-client-in-a-nested-form). If you look at that question, the part labelled "design forms here" needs scrollbars.

No matter whether I set scroll bars programatically to be visible or use the AutoScroll property - I never see the scroll bars !!   Grrrr!!   I was wondering if something else that I am doing could be removing the scroll bars. For instance `BorderStyle := bsNone;`

It's not that - when I comment it out I still don't see scrollbars, but that has got me thinking .... any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason to use a nested Form on the right side? I tried it with a TScrollBox instead (alclient) and the scrollbars appear as expected...

Comment: +1 thanks for the reply. form contains a 3rd party component. Maybe I can place it on a TScrollBox, rather than a TForm.